# Regular expressions for set of all strings on alphabet $\{a, b\}$

Tags: regular-expressions

I came across following regular expressions which equals $(a+b)^*$ (set of all strings on alphabet $\{a, b\}$):

- $(a^*+bb^*)^*$
- $(a^*b+b^*a)^*$
- $(a^*bb^*+b^*ab^*)^*(a^*b+b^*a)^*b^*a^*$

I want to generalise different ways in which we can append to original regular expression $(a+b)^*$, to not to change its meaning and still get set of all strings on alphabet $\{a, b\}$. I think we can do this in two ways :

- **P1:** We can concatenate anything to $a$ and $b$ inside brackets of $(a+b)^*$
- **P2:** We can concatenate $(a+b)^*$ with any regular expression which has star at most outer level ($(...)^*$)
- **P3:** I know $(a+b)^* = (a^*+b)^* = (a+b^*)^*= (a^*+b^*)^*$. So I guess P1 and P2 also applies to them.

Am I correct with P's?

**Q.** Also I know $(a+b)^*=(a^*b^*)^*=b^*(a^*b)^*=(ab^*)^*a^*$. Can we append some pattern of regular expressions to these also to not to change their original meaning?

Comment: You might be interested in axiomatizations for the equational theory of regular expressions (such as the two famous one due to Salomaa). These enable you to prove the equivalence of *any* two regular expressions.

Comment: Let $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$. Since you're only talking about concatenation, if $A$ is a regular expression such that $L(A) = \Sigma^*$ (i.e., $A$ is equivalent to $(a+b)^*$) and $B$ is another regular expression, then $L(AB) = \Sigma^*$ if and only if $B$ matches the empty string $\epsilon$. The "if" direction is trivial since $\Sigma^* = L(A) \subseteq L(AB) \subseteq \Sigma^*$. The "only if" direction follows from the fact that  $\epsilon \in L(A) \setminus L(B) \subseteq L(A) \setminus L(AB)$ which implies that $L(A) \setminus L(AB) \neq \emptyset$, i.e., $L(A)$ and $L(AB)$ differ.

Comment: Just to clarify my previous comment: in the "if" direction I'm assuming that $\epsilon \in L(B)$, while in the "only if" direction I'm assuming that $\epsilon \not\in L(B)$.

Comment: **Q1.** You said "...if and only if $B$ matches the empty string $ϵ$...". Isnt it same as what I said in P2 "...any regular expression which has star at most outer level ($(...)^∗$)..."? Does that mean P2 is correct? **Q2.** I did not get $\epsilon \in L(A)\setminus L(B)\subseteq L(A)\setminus L(AB)$. Do you mean left quotient by $\setminus$? Isnt $L(A)\setminus L(AB)=L(B)$. Similarly $L(A)\setminus L(B)=L(B)$ if $\epsilon\in L(A)$, right? If yes, then isnt $L(A)\setminus L(B)=L(A)\setminus L(AB)=L(B)$?